# Add a cell to my HTML table at end of each row as a true/false button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to load and show a CSV in my HTML page using JS. I am able to show the data, but now I want to add the option to add an agree/disagree or check mark/x mark at the end of each row.

So for example, the first row will show some data, and after I looked at it, I will decide if I agree with it or not. After I click agree, the whole row's variable will be set to "true" for example.

So this is my HTML:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="fileSelect" />
  <div id="status">Waiting for CSV file.</div>
  <table id="csvOutput"></table>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my script.js:

```js
function buildHeaderElement (header) {
    const headerEl = document.createElement('thead')
    headerEl.append(buildRowElement(header, true))
    return headerEl
  }

  function buildRowElement (row, header) {
    const columns = row.split(',')
    const rowEl = document.createElement('tr')

    for (column of columns) {
      const columnEl = document.createElement(`${header ? 'th' : 'td'}`)
      columnEl.textContent = column
      rowEl.append(columnEl)
    }

    return rowEl
  }


  function populateTable (tableEl, rows) {
    const rowEls = [buildHeaderElement(rows.shift())]

    for (const row of rows) {
      if (!row) { continue }
      rowEls.push(buildRowElement(row))
    }

    tableEl.innerHTML= ''
    return tableEl.append(...rowEls)
  }

  function readSingleFile ({ target: { files } }) {
    const file = files[0]
    const fileReader = new FileReader()
    const status = document.getElementById('status')

    if (!file) {
      status.textContent = 'No file selected.'
      return
    }

    fileReader.onload = function ({ target: { result: contents } }) {

        status.textContent = `File loaded: ${file.name}`
        const tableEl = document.getElementById('csvOutput')
        const lines = contents.split('\n')

        populateTable(tableEl, lines)
        status.textContent = `Table built from: ${file.name}`
    }
    fileReader.readAsText(file)
  }

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
    document.getElementById('fileSelect').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile)
  })
```

I can't figure out how to add the option I'm looking for at the end of each row, as well as how to mark each row as it's own variable.

Comment: Why can't you add a checkbox to a table cell, when you are already adding a bunch of rows and cells to the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend your code: after `rowEl.append(columnEl)`, you could call a method to append a hard-coded TD/ TH and also append a checkbox.

As the columns are dynamically created, there is no way of knowing which columns store the unique key(s). Therefore you could store the entire row as a comma separated string as an attribute on the checkbox. *Although you'll need to be careful the row data is not too long.*

```
function buildRowElement(rowData, header) {
    const columns = rowData.split(',')
    const rowEl = document.createElement('tr')

    for (column of columns) {
        const columnEl = document.createElement(`${header ? 'th' : 'td'}`)
        columnEl.textContent = column
        rowEl.append(columnEl)
    }

    rowEl.append(provideColumnAgree(rowData, header))
    return rowEl
}

function provideColumnAgree(rowData, header) {
    const columnAgree = document.createElement(`${header ? 'th' : 'td'}`)

    if (header) {
        columnAgree.textContent = 'Agree?';
    }
    else {
        const checkboxAgree = document.createElement(`input`)
        checkboxAgree.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        checkboxAgree.setAttribute("data-row", rowData);
        columnAgree.append(checkboxAgree)
    }

    return columnAgree
}
```

A working example: https://jsfiddle.net/f74pxkor/

Comment: You don't need to store any string with a checkbox. The row itself is what it pertains to and is trivially obtained through the checkbox itself (as it's parent element, for example).

Comment: Looks good, I'm not sure how to add the right amount of checkboxes though. It populates the entire page instead of just the amount of rows.

Comment: It should only add a checkbox for each table row (except header). If you're seeing more that that, then it might be the csv file has additional commas